# How do I delete only one object from canvas and not both?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have a code where every second I generate random circle on canvas. And when you click on the object you get +1 point. But count of your points gets deleted every time new circle is made. How can I do it so count is permanently displayed on canvas?

```py
import tkinter
import random
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

count=0

def motion(event):
    x,y = event.x, event.y
    global count
    if q+20 > x > q-20 and w+20 > y > w-20:
        count=count+1
        canvas.create_text(150,20,text=count)
    else:
        count=0
        canvas.create_text(150,20,text=count)
        
def game():
    canvas.delete('all')
    global q,w
    q=random.randint(20,280)
    w=random.randint(20,280)
    canvas.create_oval(q-20,w-20,q+20,w+20)
    canvas.after(1000,game)

game()

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', motion,)
```

Comment: When you create each object, give it a unique tag (using the `tags=` option), and then specify the tag of the one you want to remove (instead of `'all'`).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete the circles while leaving everything else on the canvas, give the circles a common tag. You can then delete them all via the tag.

```
canvas.create_oval(q-20,w-20,q+20,w+20, tags=("circle",))
...
canvas.delete("circle")
```

Also, you probably shouldn't be creating a new text item every time the `motion` function is called. Instead, create it once and then just change the text. You can use the same tag concept for the text so that you don't have to remember the text id.

Just do this once, outside the function:

```
canvas.create_text(150,20,text=count, tags=("text",))
```

Then, inside the function you can change the text:

```
canvas.itemconfig("text", text=count)
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import tkinter
import random

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(150, 20, text="0", tags=("text",))
count=0

def motion(event):
    x,y = event.x, event.y
    global count
    if q+20 > x > q-20 and w+20 > y > w-20:
        count=count+1
    else:
        count=0
    canvas.itemconfig("text", text=count)

def game():
    canvas.delete('circle')
    global q,w
    q=random.randint(20,280)
    w=random.randint(20,280)
    canvas.create_oval(q-20,w-20,q+20,w+20, tags=("circle",))
    canvas.after(1000,game)

game()

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', motion,)

root.mainloop()
```

As a final optimization, you don't have to continuously delete and recreate the one circle. Like with the text object, you can create the one circle and then just reconfigure its coordinates much the same as I showed how to reconfigure the text.